# Should I use a regex or a PEG to handle these use cases?

Tags: regex, parsing, peg

Examples of the data I'm looking to parse:

- Manufacturer XY-2822, 10-mill, 17-25b
- Other Manufacturer 16b Part
- Another Manufacturer WER M9000, 11-mill, 11-40
- 18b Part
- Maker 11-36, 10-mill
- Maker 1x or 2x; Max sizes 1x (34b), 2x (38/24b)

I'm trying to respectively extract:

- 17, 25
- 16
- 11, 40
- 18
- 11, 36
- 34, 38, 24

For the last one, only getting 38, 24 is also acceptable.

So, I may or may not have other numbers in the data, and I may or may not have "b" appended to the item I'm interested in. I also need to extract multiple numbers which are either separated by a dash (-) or a forward slash (/).

Should I be using a parsing expression grammar for this?

Would it be simpler to write the regex, if so, should I write several expressions or can I do this in one fell swoop?

**edit** adding more cases here, since a good answer falls apart when held to a bit more scrutiny

Answer (score 1):

I should use positive lookahead.

```
\d+(?=[^,]*$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mR7zC8/1)

Update:

Use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 1 and 2.

```
(\d+)(?:[\/-](\d+)|b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nD8uX4/2)

Comment: sorry, I added more examples above, the last two don't get captured correctly